Self referencing one-to-one SQLAlchemy
Using SQLAlchemy I'm trying to create a one-to-one relationship on the same table. This table represents some physical ethernet ports that can be connected. Here is my code:
class DevicePort(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device_ports'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    port_number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    
    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('devices.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    device = db.Relationship('Device', back_populates='ports', foreign_keys=device_id)
    
    connected_to_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('device_ports.id'), nullable=True)
    connected_to = db.Relationship('DevicePort', back_populates='connected_to', uselist=False, foreign_keys=connected_to_id,
                                   remote_side=id)

For exemple: port A, B and C. Port A.connected_to_id is set to B.id. That means that B.connected_to_id is set to A.id. If B.connect_to_id is set to C.id then A.connected_to_id is set to None and C.connected_to_id is set to B.id.
That's what I wanted but I got the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[DevicePort(device_ports)]'. Original exception was: DevicePort.connected_to and back-reference DevicePort.connected_to are both of the same direction <RelationshipDirection.MANYTOONE: 2>.  Did you mean to set remote_side on the many-to-one side ?

